# Entity did not have primary key

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven

```
@Entity

public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String productName;
    private int year;
    private Double price;
    private String url;

    public  Product() { }
     public Product(String productName, int year, Double price, String url) {
         this.productName = productName;
         this.year = year;
         this.price = price;
         this.url = url;
     }
}
```

I have a problem with my Springboot. Even when I add @Id, the log tells me that Product didn't have any Id.

Comment: Please show the full error output... how you write/save your entity...

Comment: Which `@Id` are you using... It shold be from the `javax.persistence` or `jakarta.persistence` (depending on the JPA version in use) and not the `org.springframework.data.Id` one...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add your entity class  in repository interface
eg:

```
public interface Repository extends JpaRepository<Product,Long>{
}
```

and in entity
change `private int year`
to

```
private Integer year
```

Comment: yeah I have already did that

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, everyone help me with this. I had already fixed this. The problem was IJ auto complete wrong import. In this case I have to use `javax.persistence` but IJ auto complete it to a `org.springframework.data.id`